# Apple Mach-O Linker Error in project with Coredata, when creating NSManagedObject Class

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, build-time

I have a project with Core Data, storyBoard based, and 3 classes. The Core Data purpose is to save locations on a MapKit, but when I create the class "Spot", subclass of NSManagedObject, I get this Buildtime error. It says:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Spot in:
    /Users/vitorferreira/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CoreDataCity-buwqjxltijduybepebqqghhkrqwe/Build/Intermediates/CoreDataCity.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CoreDataCity.build/Objects-normal/i386/Spot.o
    /Users/vitorferreira/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CoreDataCity-buwqjxltijduybepebqqghhkrqwe/Build/Intermediates/CoreDataCity.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CoreDataCity.build/Objects-normal/i386/Spot+CoreDataClass.o
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

In a previous comment (this is an edited question) - it's been said the reason is duplicated code in the Libraries...But honestly I don't get it...Any help would be much apreciated

Comment: Xcode8 and recently created project ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Xcode 8.2 (or maybe earlier) by default creates `NSManagedObject` subclass files completely invisibly  and automatically if you have the entity `Codegen` mode set to `Class Definition` or `Category/Extension`.

[image]

So if you have the entity set to this mode…

**DO NOT** manually generate with *Editor > Create NSManagedObject Subclass…* or you'll have two copies and duplicated symbols.

The auto-generated files live down inside the derived data folder. You can Command click the objects to get to their definitions.

[image]

and you may find when adding Entities or making big changes that it takes a Clean->Build cycle to pick it up.

If you don't want this behaviour switch `Codegen` to `Manual/None`

**NOTE**

Feb 2017 - The templates are not 100% correct and the generated `class func fetchRequest()` is not usable due to being ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

This means you have duplicate code somewhere in your libraries, have you imported core data in more than one location?

Comment: I dont think so; actually I have the same problem in a complete project. I've clean the builds, searched the librarys paths - as suggested in one post - and all i got is "Debug" and "Release"

Comment: Your post says you just created this project, does it happen again if you start a completely new project with core data?

Comment: yes, i'm trying to duplicate the other one with the same issue, but in the new one I get the error right from the start

Comment: I have no clue, I tried replication your error and couldn't.  Sorry, but good luck!

Comment: Well, I guees I'm gonna need it...:)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the name of the duplicated symbol, I'm guessing this is an Objective C project and you have the following (or similar) in both `Spot.h` and `Spot+CoreDataClass.h`:

```
@interface Spot: NSManagedObject
```

`_OBJC_METACLASS_$_Spot` is the name the compiler gives to the `Spot` metaclass, which is the type of the object returned by `+[Spot class]`.

Comment: Thanks for all the great answers, but I'll have to vote the most illustrative and usefull for others

Comment: Yes, it looks like this is new Xcode behavior. There are a number of similar questions I've seen recently.